# How to plot a function correctly?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, methods

Yes, I want to plot a function, but the problem is how to do it correctly? Does exist any method? I have got a mathematical parser for given string functions, so here, there isn't a problem... I' want know how to do:

1. Plotting
2. Zoom-in Zoom-out
3. Moving with keys ( I know how to drive the keyboard )

How you can see, I know programming, but the problem is the best method...

Any book? Any idea?

Thank you!

PS: Functions are 2D.

Comment: the question is too vague. What is your environnement? Programming language?

Comment: Object Pascal - Python - C / C++, it doesn't mind because I know programming, but I don't know wich is the best way to plot a function... If you wanna give me graphic libraries, I know a bit 'bout it...

Answer (score 2):

**Easiest**, well that would be,
 - use a library or programming environment that supports it, like

```
SciPy / matplotlib
gnuplot
Matlab
Mathematica
```

this means the least extra code needs to be written!

Comment: I've never used an external program's library... Have you got an example for using it?

Comment: You can open a pipe (e.g. with `popen`, at least on Posix systems) to the `gnuplot` command.

Comment: +1 for matplotlib. The tutrial is quite nice. http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/pyplot_tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you can use an external program to plot the function, for instance thru [GNUplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/). But not every function can be prettily plotted (because e.g. it could be continuous, but not derivable, or because its derivative function is not bounded... e.g. `x*sin(1/x)` ...)

Basically you plot a function by drawing e.g. a polygonal line between points (x_i, f(x_i))

Maybe your question is how to draw graphics on a screen. You could use graphical user interfaces (like e.g. [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) and its [Graphics View Framework](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/graphicsview.html), etc.)

Comment: No I know hot to draw graphics on a screen... I know the algorithm: x = Value, y = Object.Evaluate_Function( x ), graph( x, y )... But I've problems with zoom in - zoom out methods...

Comment: I don't understand your zoom in - zoom out issues. Zooming is just an affine change of coordinates (followed by a rectangular clipping). And the Qt links I gave are very handy for that.

Comment: Yeah! Here is the problem... How to do the change of coordinates correctly and the rectangular clipping...

Comment: Read a textbook on basic linear 2D geometry.